# Can i use replica set name to connect via mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, connection, mongodb-replica-set

I would like to know, is there a way we can replicate from one mongo replica set to another via mongo-connector? As per mongo documentation we can connect two mongo instances via mongo-connector by using a command as in the example below, but I would like to pass replica set name or use a configuration file instead of passing **server:port** name in command line.

> *Mongo Connector can replicate from one MongoDB replica set or sharded cluster to another using the Mongo DocManager. The most basic usage is like the following:*
>
> mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:37017 -d mongo_doc_manager

I also tried config.json option by creating below config.json file but it has failed.

```
{
    "__comment__": "Configuration options starting with '__' are disabled",
    "__comment__": "To enable them, remove the preceding '__'",

    "mainAddress": "localhost:27017",
    "oplogFile": "C:\Dev\mongodb\mongo-connector\oplog.timestamp",
    "verbosity": 2,
    "continueOnError": false,

    "logging": {
        "type": "file",
        "filename": "C:\Dev\mongodb\mongo-connector\mongo-connector.log",
        "__rotationWhen": "D",
        "__rotationInterval": 1,
        "__rotationBackups": 10,
        "__type": "syslog"        
    },

    "docManagers": [
        {
            "docManager": "mongo_doc_manager",
            "targetURL": "localhost:37010",
            "__autoCommitInterval": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi anyone has some suggestions on how to use configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible to connect to a replica set or a shard server using mongo connector.

```
 {
mongo-connector -m <mongodb server hostname>:<replica set port> \
            -t <replication endpoint URL, e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr> \
            -d <name of doc manager, e.g., solr_doc_manager>
}
```

you can also also pass a connection string to the mongo-connector such as

```
{
mongo connector -m mongodb://db1.example.net,db2.example.net:2500/?replicaSet=test&connectTimeoutMS=300000

}
```

to specify specifc config files you can use

```
{ mongo-connector -c config.json }
```

where config.json is your config file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried below way but it failed with below exception.
mongo-connector -m rs1 -t rs2 -d mongo_doc_manager

Comment: can you paste the exception please ?
did you saw the the configurations options page in github from mongo labs
https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Configuration%20Options

Comment: I'm trying to post my exception details because of characters limit i'm not able to post. I'm new to this community. Just give a minute.

Comment: another question, is your replica set up and running ? you also need to specify the port number
 mongo-connector -m <mongodb server hostname>:<replica set port> \
                -t <replication endpoint URL, e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr> \
                -d <name of doc manager, e.g., solr_doc_manager>

Comment: i updated my answer. please have a look. you missed port number for your replica set.

Comment: Logging to mongo-connector.log.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\util.py", line 90, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\mongo_connector-2.5.0.dev0-py3.6.egg\mongo_connector\connector.py", line 268, in run
    main_conn.admin.command("isdbgrid")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pymongo-3.3.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\pymongo\database.py", line 478, in command
    with client._socket_for_reads(read_preference) as (sock_info, slave_ok):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)

Comment: Yes my replica set is up. I created 2 config files for 2 separate mongo instances.
Config file 1:
##store data here
dbpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\data

##all output go here
logpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\log\mongo.log

logappend=true

#port number 
port=27017

##log read and write operations
diaglog=3

#replica set name
replSet=rs1

Config file 2:
dbpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\data2
logpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\log2\mongo.log
#port number 
port=37017
#replica set name
replSet=rs2

Comment: I tried with below command but again its failed

mongo-connector -m rs1:27010 -t rs2:37010 -d mongo_doc_manager

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: in the command :  mongo-connector -m rs1:27010 -t rs2:37010 -d mongo_doc_manager I assume rs1 is the replicaset name. however you need to provide your host machine name there and the port should be the one on which replicaset is running on.

Comment: You can use  mongo-connector -c config.json command and get config.json sample from mongo connector's wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to resolve my issue by entering backslash '\' for my windows directory path.Here is my updated config file for reference. Thanks to ShaneHarvey[Not able to use Configuration file for connecting to mongo-connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/527)

```
{
    "__comment__": "Configuration options starting with '__' are disabled",
    "__comment__": "To enable them, remove the preceding '__'",

    "mainAddress": "localhost:27017",
    "oplogFile": "C:\\Dev\\mongodb\\mongo-connector\\oplog.timestamp",
    "noDump": false,
    "batchSize": -1,
    "verbosity": 2,
    "continueOnError": false,

    "logging": {
        "type": "file",
        "filename": "C:\\Dev\\mongodb\\mongo-connector\\mongo-connector.log",
        "__format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s",
        "__rotationWhen": "D",
        "__rotationInterval": 1,
        "__rotationBackups": 10,
        "__type": "syslog",
        "__host": "localhost:27017"        
    },  


    "docManagers": [
        {
            "docManager": "mongo_doc_manager",
            "targetURL": "localhost:37017",
            "__autoCommitInterval": null
        }
    ]
}
```